# Internal webcamera with hi847 sensor doesn't work on alder lake platform

Tags: drivers, intel, camera, 22.10, sensors

I have dualboot system with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.10. Notebook based on intel Alder Lake platform with i5 1230u processor. Internal WebCamera (HI847) sensor doesn't work in Ubuntu, but works in Windows. I tried some Linux Kernels(from 6.0 to 6.1.9) and it didn't help. So i followed this guide https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers and installed all necessary drivers. This repos doesn't contains hi847 sensor driver, but Linux kernel does. File /dev/video0 exists, but cheese and guvcview can't recognize it (error like "/dev/video0" doens't exists). Also webcamtest.com shows me this results (discord the same).[image]
Command `dmesg | grep intel` have this lines about intel drivers:

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.9-060109-generic root=UUID=98a93879-0867-4ce1-96ff-a038112de938 ro quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 vt.handoff=7
[    0.031591] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.9-060109-generic root=UUID=98a93879-0867-4ce1-96ff-a038112de938 ro quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 vt.handoff=7
[    1.296302] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[    1.297697] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
[    1.302941] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
[    1.483021] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    1.507139] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    1.525200] intel-lpss 0000:00:19.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    1.542960] intel-lpss 0000:00:1e.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    1.555043] intel-lpss 0000:00:1e.3: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    2.798588] intel_ipu6: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.798696] intel_ipu6: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.800494] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: Device 0x465d (rev: 0x6)
[    2.800530] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: physical base address 0x603c000000
[    2.800533] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: mapped as: 0x000000003b3e1402
[    2.800624] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPU in secure mode
[    2.800626] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPU secure touch = 0x0
[    2.800629] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPU camera mask = 0xff
[    2.815687] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPC reset done
[    2.815695] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: cpd file name: intel/ipu6ep_fw.bin
[    2.818080] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: FW version: 20220510
[    2.823368] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: Sending BOOT_LOAD to CSE
[    2.832854] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: Sending AUTHENTICATE_RUN to CSE
[    2.861904] intel-hid INTC1070:00: platform supports 5 button array
[    2.900997] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: CSE authenticate_run done
[    2.901038] intel-ipu6 intel-ipu: IPU6-v3 driver version 1.0
[    2.950379] intel-ipu6-isys intel-ipu6-isys0: no subdev found in graph
[    2.983122] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: pkg_dir entry count:8
[    2.983794] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: psys probe minor: 0
[    3.078343] intel_rapl_msr: PL4 support detected.
[    3.078863] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.078870] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    3.078872] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    3.098120] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.124243] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0040-0041.sfi
[    3.217659] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
[    3.217706] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.218876] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
[    3.367590] intel_tcc_cooling: Programmable TCC Offset detected
[    4.785582] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-0040-0041.ddc
[    4.997762] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
```

And some additional info from other commands:

lsmod | grep intel

```
intel_ipu6_psys        98304  0
intel_ipu6_isys       143360  0
intel_ipu6            106496  2 intel_ipu6_isys,intel_ipu6_psys
videobuf2_dma_contig    24576  1 intel_ipu6_isys
v4l2_fwnode            32768  2 intel_ipu6_isys,hi847
v4l2_async             28672  3 v4l2_fwnode,intel_ipu6_isys,hi847
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  2 intel_ipu6_isys,uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       81920  6 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_dma_contig,videobuf2_v4l2,intel_ipu6_isys,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
videodev              282624  8 v4l2_async,videobuf2_v4l2,v4l2loopback,intel_ipu6_isys,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common,hi847
mc                     77824  7 v4l2_async,videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,intel_ipu6_isys,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common,hi847
```

dmesg | grep hi847

```
[    2.861693] hi847 i2c-HYV0847:00: can't get clock frequency
[    2.861759] hi847 i2c-HYV0847:00: failed to get HW configuration: -22
[    2.863476] hi847: probe of i2c-HYV0847:00 failed with error -22
```

v4l2-ctl --list-devices

```
ipu6 (PCI:pci:pci0000:00):
/dev/video0
ipu6 (pci:pci0000:00):
/dev/media0
Virtual Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
/dev/video1
```

hwinfo --pci (about intel multimedia controller)

```
29: PCI 05.0: 0480 Multimedia controller
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: CvwD.yvgG3eJlD40
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:05.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Intel Multimedia controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x465d 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1d72 "Xiaomi"
  SubDevice: pci 0x2115 
  Revision: 0x06
  Driver: "intel-ipu6"
  Driver Modules: "intel_ipu6"
  Memory Range: 0x603c000000-0x603cffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 16 (4 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000465Dsv00001D72sd00002115bc04sc80i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: intel_ipu6 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe intel_ipu6"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: intel_ipu6_psys is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe intel_ipu6_psys"
  Driver Info #2:
    Driver Status: intel_ipu6_isys is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe intel_ipu6_isys"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

I have no more ideas how to force it work. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: @Pilot6, I am sorry, this is my first question on Ask Ubuntu. Should i edit my question?

Comment: Correct, [edit] the question and replace terminal screenshots with text. Format it using the `{}` icon.

Comment: Thanks for the editing help!